# Azure kubernetes - multiple managed identity?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

We are planning to deploy multiple applications on our single Azure kubernetes cluster, each application will have its own set of Azure resources - eg: Key vault, Storage.

I am planning to provision individual managed identities per application and provide access to the relevant resources.

I know that AZURE AAD POD identify is the way to configure the pod to make use of the managed identity to access the Azure resources.

However how do I add multiple managed identity into the Azure kubernetes cluster? and is this the right of implementing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned before, I don't think you can add multiple MSIs to the cluster, you can just  use a system-assigned MSI or user-assigned MSI for it.

Reference - [Use managed identities in Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity)

In your case, if you want to use different service principals to authenticate(essentially MSI is also a service principal managed by Azure), you can create multiple AD Apps along with the service principals.

Reference - [How to: Use the portal to create an Azure AD application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal)

Then in the code of every application, use [`ClientSecretCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-java-stable) to authenticate.

```
ClientSecretCredential credential1 = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
     .tenantId(tenantId)
     .clientId(clientId)
     .clientSecret(clientSecret)
     .build();
```

Then use the credential to create a client e.g. SecretClient .

```
SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
    .vaultUrl("<your-key-vault-url>")
    .credential(credential1)
    .buildClient();
```

Comment: Thank you, Joy Wang. It definitely improves the auditing however still I need to have a single MSI to access the Key Vault to retrieve the clientID & clientSecret and with this MSI any application can get the clientID & clientSecret of others. Any thoughts?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar You mean you will store these values of multiple service principals in the keyvault, then you use MSI to get them and do a further authenticate? If so, I think it is feasible.